# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python

Wrote a code earlier and forgot to save it and now I am frankenstein-ing it all together- but I can't remember what I did  for this chunk and now I'm getting an error.

```
writer = open(file_name, 'w')
for i in range (len(mammal_name)):
    mammal_lbs=round((float(mammal_kg[i]))*2.2046,3)    
    brain_lbs=round((float(brain_g[i]))*.0022046,3)
    writer.write(mammal_name[i]+','+str(mammal_lbs)+','+str(brain_lbs)+'\n')
writer.close()
```

The code works fine if I don't change what's in the list or if I remove stuff.
But, in other parts of the code I add into the lists and it's giving me this error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number.

I feel like I am doing something stupid.

Comment: Well, what are you adding to `mammal_kg` and `brain_g`?

Comment: adding another number to the list- so I'm changing it from a string to a float so that it can be multiplied and rounded.

Comment: Could you show the code that adds things to the lists?

Comment: it's being added by input like a list.insert(position,input)

Comment: There is a builtin function called `input`. If you accidentally inserted that, you would get that error

Comment: I was using the built in function of input.

Comment: You could possibly do something like this `list.insert(position,input())`, but `list.insert(position,input)` is wrong

Answer (score 1):

One of you calls to `float` is receiving an invalid parameter. You could track it down like this

```
writer = open(file_name, 'w')
for i in range (len(mammal_name)):
    try:
        mammal_lbs=round((float(mammal_kg[i]))*2.2046,3)    
        brain_lbs=round((float(brain_g[i]))*.0022046,3)
    except TypeError:
        print i
        print repr(mammal_kg[i])
        print repr(brain_g[i])
        raise
    writer.write(mammal_name[i]+','+str(mammal_lbs)+','+str(brain_lbs)+'\n')
writer.close()
```